# Cannot connect to Typo3 V6.2.1 backend on windows 7

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

I have installed Typo3 on my computer (running on W7 with wamp) and I have some problem to connect to the backend.

The installation process is working fine but when I try to connect, after typing my username and password the system displays "Verifying login data..." forever. I am sure that I have typed the correct information.

I used PHP 5.3.28 (UI have tried with PHP 5.4.31 with the same result), apache 2.2.17 and MySQL 5.5.8.

Could you please help me?

Thanks,

Manu

Comment: provide your wamp log, otherwise the community can't help you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the problem was that OpenSSL was not installed.

First I ignored the problem Typo3 complained about because on a local System I was not worried about security. But the installation fixed the login issue.

Answer (score 1):

change

```
TYPO3_CONF_VARS[‘FE’][‘loginSecurityLevel’] = ‘rsa’;
```

to

```
TYPO3_CONF_VARS[‘FE’][‘loginSecurityLevel’] = ‘normal’;
```

Comment: How will this change cause the problem to go away? Can you explain what the impact changing from `rsa` to `normal` would be?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the http-calls in the browser (F12 -> Network-Tab), maybe there is a response with a helpful message!
Also check your server-logs and post more specific errors.

Check if you have all php-dependencies/modules installed and set

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

in the php.ini for your TYPO3-instance.

[Requirements for TYPO3.CMS 6.2](http://typo3.org/typo3-cms/overview/requirements/)

Answer (score 0):

If you open the browser's inspection tools, you will see that it's a ajax request that gets back with a http 500 error code. If you try this http request in the browser, you will probably get the error :

```
<t3err>No OpenSSL backend could be obtained for rsaauth.</t3err>
```

Which gives us some insight.

As stated in [Exception/CMS/1318283565](https://wiki.typo3.org/Exception/CMS/1318283565), found when googling the t2err error, it's a OpenSSL Issue. Two solutions :

- Get your openssl configuration right (see previous link)
- Fallback to a non-rsa authentication method - not recommended :

  - edit the LocalConfiguration.php, set loginSecurityLevel to normal
  - update the user hashed password in database (change 'admin' by your login) :

    ```
    UPDATE be_users SET password=md5('your_new_password') WHERE username = 'admin';
    ```